# Conditional operator vs if then else

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, conditional-statements

If I want to implement some conditional code that can be implemented in both of the ways. Then which way is better conditional operator  ?: or if..then..else??

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do.  This question isn't really answerable (even subjectively) without more info.

Comment: Try both, compare the generated assembler code or time it.

Comment: @cHao : how does it depend on what he does?he's probably asking which is better in performance

Comment: @BhavikShah: Because some cases lend themselves better to `?:`, some to `if`/`else`.

Comment: You may want to tag your question with whatever language you're using.

Comment: @cHao give me some example

Comment: @Lynn: At one point it was tagged with Java, C, and C++.  Think someone untagged it.

Comment: This might be better for codereview.stackexchange.com, but still, it needs more clarification.

Comment: if you need to have a lot of condition then 'if then else' is more readable. If you just have one condition with a little code then conditional operator is more readable.

Comment: Actually its  a general question. So I just tagged all of the languages

Comment: @cHao Indeed, just looked at the edit history.

Comment: And in general which is preferred first? Many times I am unable to decide while coding

Comment: @ShivaPareek:  It *depends on the use in question*.  If you really really can't decide, and absent any other info, go for `if`/`else`; it'll confuse fewer idiots.  But both work, and work well *for what they are for*, and using `if`/`else` where `?:` would make more sense, just looks noobish to me.

Comment: @BhavikShah I'd be very surprised if he's asking about performance.  There should be no difference, and even if there were, readability and maintainablity are more important.

Comment: because this question was asked in many interviews, so just wanted to ask the professionals here.

Comment: This question is asked in interviews?  Oi.  Not in the US.  I've never once been asked it.  I always get higher-level design questions (other than the occasional "i know a trick; do you?" questions), and i doubt i'm alone here.

Comment: Some C++ answers to a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702137/will-a-shorthand-if-provide-an-efficiency-boost-compared-to-the-default-if/13702208#13702208)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.  In general, you want the major flow of activity to
be represented in the structure of the code.  If the key point
of the algorithm is that the variable `x` is initialized, then
the best solution is to use the conditional operator:

```
x = condition ? f1() : f2();
```

If the decision is the critical issue for understanding what is
going on, then you'll prefer the `if`.  In practice, this means
that when both are reasonably possible, you'll use `?:`.  The
key being "reasonably"—if you find that you're using the
comma operator in the subexpressions, of the subexpressions have 
side effects, then using `?:` is probably not "reasonable".

### EDIT:

When you do use the `?:` operator, in all but the simplest
cases, you should format it exactly as you would an `if`, e.g.:

```
x = condition
    ? complex_expression_1
    : complex_expression_2;
```

I do this regularly.  (There's a special case where I'll push
it: if I can reduce the entire function down to a single return
statement.  I still won't allow side effects of the comma
operator, but I will sometimes use more complicated expressions
than I otherwise would.)

Comment: +1 Another criterion for "reasonable" (besides comma operators or side effects) would be if the condition or either subexpression is of such length or complexity that the overall structure of the expression wouldn't be easily recognizable to someone casually reading the code. (Perhaps that's what you were getting at with the comma operator, but the issue is more general than that.)

Comment: @TedHopp You'd be surprised at what becomes reasonable with good formatting.  Since formatting disappears in comments.  I'll edit my answer to give an example.

Comment: @JamesKanze nice explanation and one more thing I want to ask that what about compiler's lexical analysis? for if then else it might have to jump some lines, in milliseconds but time may be greater than analyzing ?: statement no?

Comment: I agree that with careful indenting, even multiply nested ternary expressions are quite readable. However, it's also surprising how much careful formatting goes out the window with ctrl-shift-f. (For instance, the default Java auto-format settings in Eclipse won't preserve your nicely indented example. Don't know about C/++/#.) Even if you manage to set your IDE to preserve this, the next person who needs to maintain your code probably won't. Goodbye readability.

Comment: @TedHopp I'll sometimes add extra parentheses just so that vim will keep the formatting.  But in general: it's usually best not to reformat something that is already formatted, precisely because none of the automatic formatters are perfect.

Comment: @ShivaPareek I can't imagine it making any measurable difference in compile times.  Although it depends.  One early C compiler I worked on implemented ?: by converting it to `if...else`, introducing extra temporary variables if necessary (which the optimizer then eliminated).  In that compiler, compiling a `?:` _was_ slower than compiling an `if ... else ...`  But nothing noticeable.

Comment: "Don't use autoformat" is fairly drastic requirement to impose on downstream maintainers. After all, maintenance involves changing code and autoformat is a very useful tool for that. Much better to use code structures that are readable after any reasonable autoformat. I tend to use ternary expressions only when they fit nicely on one line (like your first example). (C++ is a different story, because using a ternary expression can eliminate a useless default constructor invocation.)

Comment: Well thanks @JamesKanze and all of you who responded to this question of mine. Yet I am voted down but atleast gained some knowledge, and that's what important. :) Thank you all

Comment: @TedHopp "Don't use autoformat" is formulated a bit harsh.  But I've yet to find an "autoformat" which did what I wanted everywhere (although this case has never been a problem).  The result is that while I count on automatic indentation to signal missing parentheses, etc., when I'm inputting, I tend to reformat sparingly, and when I do, I more or less assume that I will have some retouching to do.  (And I will _not_ use an `if` when the logic calls for `?:`, just because some tool is broken.  The choice of one or the other is based on program logic, and nothing else.)

Answer (score 0):

They are **pretty close if not exactly the same**. Even if **there are slight differences in bytecode**.You can always do performance tests to be sure.

For checking byte code check out `javap and jad`

Comment: Unless the compiler is completely broken, the impact of the choice on performance should be 0.  The question was better, not faster, so he's obviously asking about readability and maintainability, and not performance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on compiler but in modern compiler there is no difference between if else and ternary operator.Don't trust "the compiler will always generate more efficient code if I use the conditional operator".

Comment: -1: There are differences.  Aside from performance.  They are different tools that do different jobs.